# Does the /home folder only contain user directories?

Tags: home-directory

I want to know if in Ubuntu `/home` only contain user home directories and no  other configuration files hidden  files....

Comment: Would be nice to see an official answer from Ubuntu or Debian about what they want & don't want in $HOME...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `home` directory should contain the user's personal data, including the configuration files that may be editable without risk for the system's health.
The user's home must **never** contain unprotected system files of any kind.
The configuration files are (very) often hidden (*.configuration_file_name*) or placed in hidden sub-directories, to avoid problems of order.
In a terminal (xTerm or Terminal are fine) use `cd` (without parameters) to set the current *working directory* to your `home`. Execute `ls -lAh` to have a nice list of any file in the current directory.
You can also use any graphical browser with the "Show hidden files" option enabled to manipulate hidden files.

Please, don't hesitate to comment under here if you have more questions and remember to press the left UP arrow if I'm of any help.
I suggest to follow a guide to *Unix* systems, any guide will be fine for those basic doubts. :)

Have a nice day.

Comment: +1 for this great and correct explanation. see eg. `.firefox` configuration directory.

Comment: "The home directory should contain directories named after users except root and those contain the user's personal data," would be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

By default `/home/` only contains user home directories (and probably a `lost+found` directory if `/home/` is on its own partition).

But as it is just a directory an admin may place other things there by accident or for some purpose.

Comment: Does it not contain hidden config files, that are user specific?

Comment: User specific files are not in `/home/` but in the user's home directory (usually `/home/username/`).

Comment: Ah, Lol missed that!

Comment: @FlorianDiesch I think if you say `/home` you can count `/home/me`, too. Else the question yould be'very stupid. See `ls -a /home` in this inode are only subdirectorys.

Comment: @LittleByBlue "/home/me" would be an assumption and the question should have specified that subdirectories are to be considered in the answer. As it is now this is the correct answer purely looking at the question.